# juju bootstrap gives this error: failed to create dqlite connection

Tags: juju, cloud, lxd, cluster

I'm trying to bootstrap juju on a lxd cluster cloud

Here the transcript of the command

```
sysop@kvmnode1:~/SVILUPPO/for_juju$ sudo juju bootstrap lxd-cloud                                                                                                              
Creating Juju controller "lxd-cloud-default" on lxd-cloud/default                                                                                                              
Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.6.2 for amd64                                                                                                                        
To configure your system to better support LXD containers, please see: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/production-setup.md                                          
Launching controller instance(s) on lxd-cloud/default...
 - Create container from image: Failed to set apply_template volatile key: Failed to update database: failed to begin transaction: failed to create dqlite connection: no avail - juju-b3db51-0 (arch=amd64)          
Installing Juju agent on bootstrap instance
Fetching Juju GUI 2.14.0
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to 240.11.0.27:22
Connected to 240.11.0.27
Running machine configuration script...
Bootstrap agent now started
Contacting Juju controller at 240.11.0.27 to verify accessibility...

Bootstrap complete, controller "lxd-cloud-default" now is available
Controller machines are in the "controller" model
Initial model "default" added
sysop@kvmnode1:~/SVILUPPO/for_juju$
```

Juju is installed by snap and is version 2.6.2

LXD is version 3.13

The lxd cluster is on 3 kvm virtual machines. All os host and guests are Kubuntu 18.04 updated today.

What this error means?

How can avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange error. It looks like output from an internal database (an instance of [dqlite](https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/dqlite)).

However, it looks like Juju installed itself correctly. Can you try the following command? If it works okay, then hopefully the situation isn't so bad.

```
juju deploy ubuntu
```

You can check to see if this worked by checking the output of `juju status`. After a minute or so, you should see `active` on the line with the `ubuntu` application.

If this doesn't work, try restarting the controller machine. You can do this manually via SSH or via Juju:

```
juju ssh -m controller 0
sudo reboot now
```

Once the machine has restarted, the system should reset itself. `juju deploy ubuntu` should work.